# Order by not working with group by clause

Tags: php, mysql

I am using corequery of mysql in cakephp. I want the records in descending order. This is my table structure[image]

```
enter code here
$coreQueryUser = $this->Message->query(
            "select * from messages where messages.list_id = 3 
            group By (if(sender_id > reciever_id,  sender_id, reciever_id)), 
                (if(sender_id > reciever_id,  reciever_id, sender_id))
            order by id desc
            "
        );
```

I want last message that belongs to (sender_id and reciver_id and viceversa) that belongs to list id 3

when i run this query i get the following output

```
<pre>Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [messages] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [sender_id] => 21
                [reciever_id] => 10
                [list_id] => 3
                [message] => hello
                [add_date] => 2016-09-25 00:00:00
                [is_check] => 0
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [messages] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [sender_id] => 22
                [reciever_id] => 10
                [list_id] => 3
                [message] => hello s
                [add_date] => 2016-09-25 16:39:41
                [is_check] => 0
            )

    )
```

)

but i wnat result like that:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [messages] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [sender_id] => 10
                    [reciever_id] => 21
                    [list_id] => 3
                    [message] => hello sir
                    [add_date] => 2016-09-25 00:00:00
                    [is_check] => 0
                )
```

`)

[1] => Array
    (
        [messages] => Array
            (
                [id] => 6
                [sender_id] => 22
                [reciever_id] => 10
                [list_id] => 3
                [message] => new
                [add_date] => 2016-09-25 16:39:41
                [is_check] => 0
            )

    )`

)

Can anyone help me :(

Comment: can you please post your expected and actual result in human readable form please. (rows and columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your query is against the sql standard because you have several fields in the select list that are neither in the group by list, nor are subject of an aggregate function, such as `sum()`. MySQL unfortunately allows such invalid queries to run under certain sql mode settings (the default settings of the most recent versions of MySQL would prevent such queries from running).

As MySQL documentation on [group by clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) says (bolding is mine):

> If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard
>   SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or
>   ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns
>   are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL
>   to accept the preceding query. **In this case, the server is free to
>   choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the
>   values chosen are indeterminate**, which is probably not what you want.
>   **Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be
>   influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Result set sorting occurs
>   after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which
>   value within each group the server chooses.**

You apparently want the latest record (with `max(id)` for each group. The proper way is to have a subquery that returns the `max(id)` per group and in the outer query join back to your main table using the ids to get the value of the other fields:

```
select m.*
from
messages m
inner join (
            select max(id) as maxid
            from messages
            where messages.list_id = 3 
            group By (if(sender_id > reciever_id,  sender_id, reciever_id)), 
            (if(sender_id > reciever_id,  reciever_id, sender_id))
           ) t1 on m.id=t1.maxid
```

Comment: Thank you Shadow. works like charm
There is one more problem how to find users who have  message on list id 3 in same query and i do not want that user who have created list id 3 .  I have one user table also Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That's a different question and you should ask it in its own topic. Just make sure explain how the tables are connected (although that will pretty much be the solution :))

Comment: Thanks for reply :) Bassically i am building chat module in our app through webservices. I have one Table of user and one is for listing and one is message table. In this Example the user who have create listing is user id 10. I want query like that fetch the last messages of list id 3 and also find the users corresponding to that but i don't want that user in result who have created that listing i.e. i don't want the user who have user id is 10

Comment: As I wrote above: ask it separately in its own post.

Answer (score 1):

This code working:

```sql
SELECT * FROM generate_invoice
WHERE id IN 
(
    SELECT max(id) as id
    FROM generate_invoice 
    GROUP by pay_id 
    ORDER by id DESC
)
```

Comment: thanks working i found this in many places but no code working correctly

Answer (score 0):

How to `group by DESC order`

Try

```
 SELECT * FROM (  SELECT * FROM generate_invoice ORDER BY id DESC ) AS g GROUP BY g.pay_id
```

OR

Use this code

```
SELECT m1.*,m2.* FROM generate_invoice m1 LEFT JOIN generate_invoice m2 ON (m1.pay_id = m2.pay_id AND m1.id < m2.id ) order by m1.id desc
```